# Is it possible to send an Ethernet packet from a logical interface to itself using Scapy?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, scapy, ethernet

I am working with raw Ethernet, so I don't need any IP or anything higher. I just want to send an Ethernet packet out of my ethernet interface `(enp0s31f6)`, to itself, and I want to be able to view these packets in Wireshark, or tcpdump. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I've tried:

```
from scapy.all import *

g = Ether(dst=get_if_hwaddr("enp0s31f6"))
sendp(g, iface="enp0s31f6")
```

The output is:

```
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

but I don't see anything being sent out of my ethernet interface on wireshark.

I've also tried seeing if I can just send an empty packet to localhost from my Ethernet interface by doing:

```
g = Ether()/IP(dst="127.0.0.
sendp(g, iface="enp0s31f6")
```

Again, scapy is claiming the packet is being sent but I cannot see it on Wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: Ethernet is a series of layer-1/2 protocols, and it requires a hardware handshake, sending and receiving a preamble and SoF delimiter on the wire. You would need to configure a loopback. Some interfaces have the ability to configure a loopback on the interface, but you will probably need a physical, external loopback plug (not simple for 1000Base-T 1 Gbps).

Comment: @RonMaupin I understand this is how it would typically need to be done. I was wondering if I can "virtualize" the packets so that

Comment: A I explained, you need a loopback, either enabled in the physical interface or with a physical loopback plug.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the packets are being sent but not being captured by Wireshark or tcpdump. To verify that the packets are indeed being sent, you can try capturing the packets using another interface on a different machine and verifying that the packets are being received.

If you still cannot see the packets on Wireshark or tcpdump, you may need to check your network configuration. Make sure that your Ethernet interface is properly configured and that there are no firewalls or other network devices blocking the packets.

You can also try using a different tool to send and capture packets, such as netcat or socat. This may help you isolate the issue and determine whether the problem is with your code or with the network configuration.